# BadMethodCallException for existing function

Tags: php, laravel

Using laravel v10.34.2 and PHP 8.2.13
Inside
routes\api.php

I have this:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Route::get('/hello', [App\Http\Controllers\MyController::class, 'hello']);
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return [1, 2, 3, 4];
});
```

Inside
app\Http\Controllers\MyController.php

I have this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function hello(Request $request)
    {
        return response(['user' => 'jack'], 200);
    }
}
```

When I go to
http://localhost:9001/api/test

It works. So I see the array with integers.

When I go to
http://localhost:9001/api/hello

I get this error:

```
Method App\Http\Controllers\MyController::hello does not exist.
Did you mean App\Http\Controllers\MyController::callAction() ?
```

I really dont understand what is wrong. App\Http\Controllers\MyController::hello exists.
So why it is complaining?

I am expecting the page
http://localhost:9001/api/hello

to show the response handled by MyController

Comment: Do you have any other controller named with MyController?

Comment: Change the controller's file name & class name and then check if it works or not.

Comment: For some reason, all the controllers created with php artisan will fail as described in the question. Creating a controller manually works. The code for the failing and succeeding ones is the same. I dont know what the problem could be.Both use same signture for class name and filename. Im on ubuntu in windows wsl. Could that cause the issue for some reason?